# Correct architecture for XMPP based messaging app using Smack API

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, messaging, smack

I am writing an XMPP based chat application for Android using the Smack API.

I have an Application class which contains all the XMPP related functions (such as connect, send message, listen for messages, invitations, presence etc.). I have put all the listeners in a separate function (startAllListeners) which is called from my splash screen when the application starts. I am unsure of the architecture to use to optimize performance of the app. Sometimes I get the *250 frames were skipped* info in my log. I am guessing this is more of a multithreading question than an XMPP question. I have seen code samples where some people have created a separate Background Service which handles all the listeners. I have also seen some code where the listeners are tightly coupled with activities (which I am a bit uncomfortable doing). So my question is,  **What is the right way to organize all the xmpp functions and whats the correct place to put all the listeners.**

My Application class looks like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public synchronized static MyApplication getInstance() {}
public void onTerminate() {}
public static XMPPTCPConnection getConnection() {}
public boolean connectToXMPP(final String username, final String password) {}
public static boolean ifUserExist(String username){}
public static void sendMessage(String message, String roomUniqueId){}
public MultiUserChat createRoom(String roomname, String roomdesc) throws Exception {}
public void joinRoom(MultiUserChat muc){}
public void inviteToRoom(MultiUserChat muc, String inviteeJID){}
public List<String> getRoomOccupants(String roomName)throws XMPPException    {}
public boolean destroyMUC(MultiUserChat muc) {}
public boolean bookmarkRoom(String roomId){}
public List<BookmarkedConference> getBookmarkedRooms(){}
public void startAllListeners(){
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>  backgroundThread= new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            StanzaTypeFilter message_filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class);
            StanzaTypeFilter presence_filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Presence.class);

            connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Packet contents are " + packet.toString());
                }
            }, message_filter);
            connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                    Presence presence = (Presence) packet;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Packet contents are " + packet.toString());
                    Log.e(TAG, "Presence update from " + presence.getFrom());
                }
            }, presence_filter);
            PacketCollector messageCollector = connection.createPacketCollector(message_filter);
            PacketCollector presenceCollector = connection.createPacketCollector(presence_filter);

            manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            manager.addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
                @Override
                public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection conn, MultiUserChat room, String inviter, String reason, String password, Message message) {
                    Log.e("Invitation received", "Got an invitation from " + inviter);
                    try {
                        room.join(getUsername());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendStanza(presence);
                Log.e(TAG, "Logged In as " + connection.getUser());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    backgroundThread.execute();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **the best way** to me is what fits, in terms of performance, others might go for design layout or something else -(btw, i am no genius or guru)..

So if i were to do something like this i would put all listeners in a Service probably break down each listener to a Service; this might depend on how your architect your app, as you might be pushing messages whiles user is offline to notify them, and you will also have to connect to your servers or other *connect, send message, listen for messages, invitations, presence etc*, if all what to be on one Service well, that Service needs to live forever, if you divide them you save resources and time or productively -which goes with responsiveness. Either way depends solely on how you design your apps, so pick a design structure and choose the way to go..

Like the known practice - Hard jobs goes to the background `IntentService` or `Thread` and UI stuff on the Main Thread. Separation of Powers helps identify who the boss is and who is responsible for what, and it is easier to ping point.